# Removing parentheses from formatted year field in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am finalizing an article, and the journal's editorial staff has asked me to put the year of publication in the reference without parentheses.
For example:

> Alighieri, D. (1321) *Comedy*.

-->

> Alighieri, D. 1321. *Comedy*.

`\bibliography{references}` in the file ".tex." `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` in the file ".sty"
This is mwe of one of my bibliography entries

```
@inproceedings{sugimoto:hal-01539048, 
  TITLE  = {{Number game - Experience of a European research 
           infrastructure (CLARIN) for the analysis of web traffic}}, 
  AUTHOR = {Sugimoto, G.}, 
  URL    = {hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01539048}, 
  BOOKTITLE = {{Proceedings of the CLARIN Annual Conference 2016, 
               26-28 September 2016, Aix-en-Provence, France}}, 
  YEAR   = {2016}, 
}
```

I use this command:

```
\bibliography{references}
```

Can I you help me please?

Comment: There's no way to answer a question like this without knowing if you're using bibtex, or biblatex, and what bibliography style file and other citation packages (natbib for bibtex, etc.) you're using. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: You are absolutely right. My fault.
I am using bibtex and acl style

Comment: Please state the exact argument of `\bibliographstyle`.

Comment: I asked for a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Did you read the link? Failing that, if you're really finalizing it, and the bibliography is not going to change again, you could just remove `\bibliography{references}` and replace it with the contents of the `.bbl` file, and manually edit that. Annoying if you have a big bibliography, but still might be easier than trying to rewrite the style.

Comment: Ugh. Don't put code in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: Sorry. I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to copy [apalike.bst](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/base/apalike.bst) into the same folder as your project.

Open it in a text editor. Find the portion (around line 120):

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
      " (" year * extra.label * ")" *
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
```

And change it to:

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
      " " year * extra.label * "" *
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
```

And save and rerun bibtex.

Comment: Great!

It works!!

Thank you very much!